# Java: How do I find a folder with only part of the word?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get back a string that contains the path to a folder.
I want to do it with just a part of the folder name.

So say I have a folder called "example-1" in "usr/share/example-1", I want to be able to get that path by matching "usr/share/ex".

Comment: You can start at the already **given folder** (`usr/share/`) and search the filesystem from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just start at the last completely given directory (`usr/share/`) and search for a file that starts with the rest (`ex`).

Therefore first separate **complete** from **incomplete**:

```
String input = ...

int lastDirIndex = input.lastIndexOf("/");
String lastDirText = input.substring(0, lastDirIndex);
String prefix = input.substring(lastDir + 1);
```

Then parse the directory `lastDirText`, get all its files and filter for the ones that start with `prefix`:

```
Path dir = Paths.get(lastDirText);
List<Path> matchingFiles = Files.walk(dir, 1)
    .filter(path -> path.getFileName().startsWith(prefix))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The list `matchingFiles` then contains all files that match the given prefix.

If you don't want to limit the search to only **one depth level** you may adjust the depth in the `Files#walk` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-)) method or even completely leave it away for **maximal depth**. You can also set some `FileVisitOption`s in this method.